# Best way to create a backup of Java Object with references of other Objects which need to be viewed later

Tags: java, spring, oop, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

When running a test I want to be able to reference all of the details at the moment the test was run at a later date.  Because the original test and its objects can constantly change I need a way to make a backup at the point when the test is run. This requires making backup's of the items used by the `TestRun`.  Essentially I want to make a backup of the current state of the objects.

Basic breakdown of the objects, `TestRun` has a set of `TestSuite`s and `SomeObject`.  It also has various attributes.  `TestSuite` contains a set of `TestCase`s.

TestRun

- set of TestSuites
- set of SomeDevices

TestSuite

- set of TestCases

TestCase

- some attributes

SomeObject

- some attributes

I was wondering the best way to archive these objects at the point in which the test is run so that we can view the TestRun at the time it was ran since the original can be edited in the future.    I was originally planning on creating `ArchiveObjects` for each of the classes which `extend` the current class.

example:

```
ArchiveTestCase extends TestCase
```

I would then create a service to check to see if the Archive Object already exists, if not build it.  But I believe this approach would not work since I would want the Archived Objects to reference the other Archived Objects which could not happen when extending from the original Object.

I also thought I could rebuild the Archived Test Run from the `TestRun` and all its `Objects`

To backup TestRun (pseudo code)

```
ArchivedTestRun archivedTestRun = new ArchivedTestRun(TestRun) // only copies attributes

// set to hold archived test suites
Set testSuites = new Set<ArchivedTestSuites>();

// get test suites
for (TestSuite ts : TestRun.getTestSuites()) {

  // set to hold archived test cases
  Set testCases = new Set<ArchivedTestCase>();

  // get test cases
  for (TestCase tc : ts.getTestCases()) {

     ArchivedTestCase archivedTestCase = new ArchivedTestCase(tc); // copies attributes
     save(archivedTestCase);
  }

  // create archive for Test Suite
  ArchivedTestSuite archivedTestSuite = new ArchivedTestSuite(ts); // copies attributes 
  archivedTestSuite.setTestCases(testCases);
  save(archivedTestSuite);
}

archivedTestRun.setTestSuites(testSuites);
save(archivedTestRun);

... // add section in to do the same for SomeObject
```

**Question**

Is the above approach a good way to do backup's of object structures?  If not what is the best process for creating a backup of `TestRun` since it has different `Set`'s it references.   Do I need to use a ground up approach and build the ArchivedObjects myself (Go into each set, copy the object to a ArchivedObject.or is their a easier/better solution.

**TestRun**

```
public class TestRun {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<TestSuite> testSuites;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<SomeObject> someObjects;

    String .... (some attributes)
    ...
}
```

**TestSuite**

```
public Class TestSuite {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<TestCase> testCases;

    ...
}
```

**TestCase**

```
public Class TestCase {
    ...
}
```

**SomeObject**

```
public Class SomeObject {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is this using JPA?  If so, have you looked at http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/ ?

Comment: What about just serializing the objects into say a Json file and then writing to an external datastore?

Comment: if you have access to logs, just log the objects you need. You can then access it whenever you need without wasting space on db and power on implementation